# $\mathbb Z^n$ is enumerable where $n\in \mathbb N$ or not??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\mathbb Z^n$ is enumerable where $n\in \mathbb N$

I cant define  a map from N $\to \mathbb Z^n $

Is it possible to define a map?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Looking up the Cantor pairing function will point you in the right direction.

Comment: It is easy to construct an injection from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ into $\mathbb{Q}$, and it is sufficient to prove countability, as the latter is countable. Take $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ $n$ distinct primes. Then $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\longmapsto p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_n^{x_n}$ is such an injection, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian product of two countable sets is again countable.  To see this, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are countable, with enumerations $A=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and $B=\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$.

Consider the sequence in $A\times B$ constructed as follows:

$$(a_1,b_1),(a_1,b_2),(a_2,b_1),(a_1,b_3),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_1),\ldots (a_1,b_k),(a_2,b_{k-1}),\ldots, (a_k,b_1),\ldots$$

Here, we first present those (finitely many!) ordered pairs such that the sum of our indices equals $2$, then $3$, etc.  Within each finite block, the elements are ordered by increasing index in the second position.  This gives an enumeration of $A \times B$, hence $A \times B$ is countable.

To show that the product of $n$ countable sets is countable, we use induction.

Answer (score 1):

A mapping is:

$1 \mapsto (0,0,\dots , 0)$

$2 \mapsto (1,0,\dots , 0)$

$3 \mapsto (0,1,\dots,0)$

$\vdots$

$n + 1 \mapsto (0, \dots, 0, 1)$

edit:

$n +2 \mapsto (1,1,0,\dots,0)$

$\vdots$

$n + 1 + {n \choose 2} \mapsto (0,\dots , 0,1,1)$

$n + 2 + {n\choose 2} \mapsto (1,1,1,0 \dots 0)$

$\vdots$

$n + 1 + {n \choose 2} +{n \choose 3} \mapsto (1,1,1,1,0 \dots, 0)$

$\vdots$

Continue in the fashion until all ways to place only zeros and ones have been exhausted. Then work through all ways to place zeros, ones, and negative ones.

Work through next all ways to place 0, 1, -1, 2. Each of these steps represents a finite number of elements, but at each stage the process becomes more time consuming.

Comment: I don't think I can guess what you meant to follow on the dots beyond $2n+2$. The most obvious way to proceed will only generate vectors with at most one nonzero entry.

Comment: You are very correct, that's a bad mapping. For some reason I was thinking only mapping to the axis. At each stage where you introduce a new number ie, 2n+2, you would need to exhaust all combinations of the preceding numbers with 2 in the first position, then again in the second position, and so on, once all possibilities of one 2 are exhausted, you could then exhaust all ways to have 2 twos, and all preceding numbers. This process repeats until you reach the vector of all 2s.

Each step above is a finite number of combinations, however, it becomes nearly impossible to define.

Answer (score 0):

A map need not be defined in terms of basic arithmetic. There are plenty of bijections you can come up with.

For example, let $C_i = [-i, i]^n$. Map $C_1$ to the first $3^n$ natural numbers. Then map $C_2 - C_1$ to the next $5^n - 3^n$ numbers. Continue mapping $C_m - C_{m-1}$ the same way. Note that $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in C_{\max\{x_i\}}$, thus every integer vector is mapped to a finite natural number.

Another example. It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) that an injection $A \to B$ and an injection $B \to A$ give a bijection. Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}^n$ be $m \mapsto (m, 0, \dots, 0)$ and let $g : \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ be $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto \prod p_i^{\phi(n_i)}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number and $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective.